# Is there a clean way to make a program wait for an observable timer?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm learning reactive and I'm playing with this test class:

```
public class ObserverTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable
                .interval(10, SECONDS)
                .takeUntil(Observable.timer(30, SECONDS))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is just to print out a sequence of integers every 10 seconds for 30 seconds. What happens of course is that the program runs through immediately and just exits.

Is there a nice RX tool that will help make my program wait until the timer has completed? I would prefer not having to deal with threading directly.

Comment: [takeWhile?](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html). TakeWhile(time!=30)

Comment: @masp no, that is not a blocking call

Comment: No it's not. Misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by calling a `blockingSubscriber` instead of just a `subscriber`